# Can i declare a docker-compose service name as environment variable in vite react app?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, docker-compose, environment-variables, vite

I cant get my docker-compose.yml file to use the service name to connect to my backend app correctly.

Im using docker-compose to run my 2 applications.

1. A Vite - react app called "frontend"
2. A backend node.js express app called "backend".

I expect my frontend to do GET and POST requests to the backend service.
Right now when i look in the network tab for my frontend the request are being sent to: `http://backend:5000/my-endpoint`

and i thought that would work, but i get: `net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED` on all request sent by my frontend app.

my docker-compose.yml looks like this:

```
version: '3'
services:
  frontend:
    build:
      context: ../frontend
    ports:
      - "5173:5173"
    environment:
      - VITE_BACKEND_HOST_URL=http://backend:5000  
    networks:
      - skystack_net
  backend:
    build:
      context: ../backend
    ports:
      - "5000:5000" #
    depends_on:
      - mongodb
    environment:
      - PORT=5000
      - DOCKER_ENV=true
    networks:
      - skystack_net
  mongodb:
    image: mongo:latest
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    networks:
      - skystack_net
    volumes:
      - mongo-data:/data/db
volumes:
  mongo-data:
networks:
  skystack_net:
```

in my react app i want to either use the environment variable set by docker-compose, or use localhost so i can start my react app locally (not in docker). so i use this const in my reat app to set the api endpoint:

`const BACKEND_HOST_URL = import.meta.env.VITE_BACKEND_HOST_URL || 'http://localhost:5000';`

but then i get this `net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED` error.

if i change the environment value from :

```
 environment:
      - VITE_BACKEND_HOST_URL=http://backend:5000
```

to:

```
 environment:
      - VITE_BACKEND_HOST_URL=http://172.25.176.1:5000
```

then it works, but i dont want to have to specify the host machine, that will be problematic if i try to run this setup on a different machine.

Should i do in another way? anny suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If internally access between containers then you can use `backend:5000`, but since you're developing a Frontend app, which you will load on your browser. Your browser is no longer a part of Docker network and it's in the host network (localhost...).

So for this to work, you have to expose backend to port `5000` which make it available in the computer that you host your Docker. And then `localhost:5000` would work.

```
environment:
      - VITE_BACKEND_HOST_URL=http://localhost:5000
```